# System event timer_changed is not called in Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, service, window

Unable to call this system event in Windows service, how can we call it in Windows service?

```
 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimeChanged += SystemEvents_TimeChanged;
void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AnyMethodExample();            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> This event is only raised if the message pump is running. In a Windows
>   service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been
>   started manually, this event will not be raised.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are calling within windows service. You can post complete code for further support. Simply,

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TimeChanged: {0}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

***Caution***: Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.